# Create new page in Webtop

Tags: documentum, webtop

How do I create a new webpage in the Documentum front end Webtop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why WebTop?  You should use Web Publisher which is built on WebTop with the specific purpose of managing web content. Is this an OOTB installation?  Web Publisher / WebTop requires significant amount of customization in order to start being useful.  Do you have templates defined?  If so, then just go to File New and select your template.

http://www.dmdeveloper.com/  Is a good site with some very good how-to's.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that it can not be done.

WebTop is Documentum's generic application for browsing their back-end content repository. Think of it as a web-based Windows Explorer on steroids. It's a tool for storing, versioning, and sharing electronic documents (Word, Excel, etc.) - it's not a tool for creating web pages.

Documentum's Web Content Management product is called Web Publisher. It is the tool that companies use to allow non-technical business users to create and edit web pages.