# Modify Clipboard content after copy event: JavaScript, jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, clipboard, clipboarddata

**My requirement:** When user copy some content from my web page, with text some HTML tags and carriage retun also gets copied. I need to modify the copied content in clipboard i.e. removing carriage retunn and HTML tags.

**What I have tried so far:**
I have captured the copy even using jQuery and get the content of clipboard. See below code.

```
$(document).bind('copy', function () {
      //getting clipboard content
      var selectedText = window.getSelection().toString();

      //removing carriage retun from content
      selectedText = selectedText.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "");

      //Trying to set data in clipboard
      window.clipboardData.setData(selectedText); //Throws error
}
```

Now, when I tried to setData in clipboard using `window.clipboardData.setData(selectedText);` , it throws error.

**Questions:**

**1) Am I using the correct function i.e. `setData()` to modify the clipbard content or not?**

**2) Can somebody let me know how can I modify the content of clipboard here?**

Comment: *it throws error.*, giving us the actual error may help us help you ;)

Comment: Also, why not update the content where it ends up? For example, why not remove them when the user pastes the content in some input etc... Dealing with the clipboard seems unnecessarily complicated

Comment: *"Throws error"* ...  don't you think the error message might be helpful here?

Comment: Take a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript

Comment: **"Unexpected call to method or property access."** this is the error I'm getting. Also, I wanted to check am I using the correct function to update the clipboard content or not?

Comment: @DelightedD0D I only have to update the data in clipboard only and have to done in _copy_ event and not in _paste_ event

Comment: @BenTemple-Heald [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40021...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript) is talks about copy the content where as I'm more concerned about modifying the copied content in clipboard.

Comment: @GeekyNinja Hooking onto peoples copies is not really possible due to security considerations, for example, they copy "http://www.google.com" from a text box, you could change that to a JS call, that when they copy it into a browser windows it downloads a virus (if they are not paying attention)

A solution, is to add a "copy" button to the end of the box that you want them to copy from, that takes the content, parses it, and then does what I linked (fired off of a button click)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176861/ ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To resolve this issue what I have done on `copy` event I have bind a function i.e. `copyToClipboard` which creates a `textarea` at run time, copy modified clipboard data to this text area and then execute a 'CUT' command (to avoid recursive call on copy event). And finally deleting textarea element in finally block.

**Code:**

```
$(document).bind('copy', function () {
            var text = window.getSelection().toString().replace(/[\n\r]+/g, '');
            copyToClipboard(text);
        });

        function copyToClipboard(text) {
                var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
                textarea.textContent = text;
                textarea.style.position = "fixed";
                document.body.appendChild(textarea);
                textarea.select();
                try {
                    return document.execCommand("cut");
                } catch (ex) {
                    console.warn("Copy to clipboard failed.", ex);
                    return false;
                } finally {
                    document.body.removeChild(textarea);
                }
        }
```

Comment: Ty for the 'cut' part. I was getting the copy recursion loop error too and didn't know what to do :P

Answer (score 24):

The currently accepted answer is overly complicated, and causes weird behavior where a user's selection is removed after copy.

Here is a much simpler solution:

```
document.addEventListener('copy', function(e){
  var text = window.getSelection().toString().replace(/[\n\r]+/g, '');
  e.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', text);
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 5):

There are two things I can find out.

1. clipboardData object will be in callback object `e` passed not in `window`.
2. the correct syntax for setData is like below.

For further reference [copy Event MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/copy)

```
document.addEventListener('copy', function(e) {
  console.log('copied');
  e.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', 'Hello World!');
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: I have tried, but *e.clipboardData* object is coming _undefined_. Not working :(

Comment: Which browser you are trying ?

Comment: I'm using Internet Explorer 9

Comment: Yes. IE9 dont have support for clipboardData at all. Check this out http://caniuse.com/#search=clipboarddata

Answer (score 0):

Bind the element id with copy event and then get the selected text. You could replace or modify the text. Get the clipboard and set the new text. To get the exact formatting you need to set the type as "text/hmtl".
You may also bind it to the document instead of element.

```
         $(ElementId).bind('copy', function(event) {
            var selectedText = window.getSelection().toString(); 
            selectedText = selectedText.replace(/\u200B/g, "");

            clipboardData = event.clipboardData || window.clipboardData || event.originalEvent.clipboardData;
            clipboardData.setData('text/html', selectedText);

            event.preventDefault();
          });
```